# Problem in Exercise of Module Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have question about exercise module theory in Hartley's book.

Find a natural way of making $M_n(R)$ into an $R$-module, and show that then $M_n(R)\cong {}_RR\oplus\ldots\oplus{}_RR$, the external direct sum of ${}_RR$ with itself $n^2$ times.

My question:

(1) What the meaning of "find a natural way"?

(2) To prove $M_n(R)\cong {}_RR\oplus\ldots\oplus{}_RR$, it must be shown that there exist an isomorphism between $M_n(R)$ and ${}_RR\oplus\ldots\oplus{}_RR$. How to define the mapping for this problem such that it can be an isomorphism?

Comment: "Natural" means compatible with homomorphisms $R \to S$.  Also, do you see how $R \otimes R$ is naturally an $R$-module?

Comment: Randall is formally of course correct, but for here also, “natural” really just means what seems most “natural/plausible/easiest...” to you. (That will ultimately give the def Randall is talking about.) And for the isomorphism, well... find the natural isomorphism. Think about why you would feel these are isomorphic.

Comment: Oops, I said tensor when I meant $\oplus$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.
It obvious that $M_n(R)$ is a module over ring $R$. So to "find a natural way of making $M_n(R)$ is a module over ring $R$", what we must do?